# Contact form 7 only send if select is 1

Tags: if-statement, contact-form-7, spam-prevention

for a small local business I am trying to fix their spam orders.

they have multiple select option in their order form and I would like to filter that atleast 1 is selected.

```
[select gerookte-zalm "0" "1" "2" "3" "4"] Meal 1
[select gerookte-zalm "0" "1" "2" "3" "4"] Meal 2
```

etc.

If nothing is ordered: (so all selects are 0 which is default) it should not be able to send.

Is this possible?

Comment: Make the field required

Comment: That doesn't really seem like the solution here. I want the SUM of the select boxes to be greater than 1. Making them required would mean people ordering everything off the menu. Great for sales, but not the goal

Comment: You can use the hook `wpcf7_before_send_mail` one of the three parameters is abort